# margin auto centers for server and IE but on chrome off server it looks like it's on the right side

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, bootstrap-4

For some reason when I open my page on chrome it looks like it start athe middle and ends on the right side. But when I run it on my server or try it on I.E 11 it looks center. why is that? It did not have this problem 30minute ago I went for lunch and then bam.

Comment: if I zoom out a lot it looks center. But my default it looks like it's on the right

Comment: can you provide some code css , html or js...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using element select the class selector had a different format. and has a higher priority